# IF Statement not closed error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm getting an error with an IF statement, even though it was working previously.

**This is my code:**

```
Hello %%[IF Empty(@firstname) THEN]%%homeowner, %%[ELSE]%% %%=ProperCase(@firstname)=%%,%% [ENDIF]%%
```

**This is the error I'm getting:**

*An IF statement is not closed with the required ENDIF statement. ClientID: ######### JobID: 0 EmailID: 0 Index: 447 Statement: IF Empty(@firstname) THEN]%%homeowner, %%[ELSE]%% %%=ProperCase(@firstname)=%%,%% [ENDIF]%%
 
 This letter serves as formal notice of your completion date at project.
 
 Your completion is %%[IF Empty(@closedate) THEN]%%(date unavailable, please email us) %%[E*

I've checked through the code and looked at resources online, but the brackets look correct to me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: There was a space before [ENDIF] I missed because of line breaks. This is the winning code:

```
Hello %%[IF Empty(@firstname) THEN]%% homeowner, %%[ELSE]%% %%=ProperCase(@firstname)=%%, %%[ENDIF]%%
```